# Setup Context API in react app (TypeScript) and pass the auth state to all components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a react app with GraphQL using Apollo-client.
I want to store userID and token after login using `Context API` and to use inside all child component's to check user authentication.

My Context setup

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

interface IAuthContext {
  auth: object;
  setAuth: Function;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext | null>(null);

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({ userId: '', getAuth: false });

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Here is an example app for my useCase [CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/auth-context-example-71jmh)

It works properly in codesandbox but not in my local machine.
I get the following error
[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEvv1.png)

In codesandbox in `App.tsx` file, the TS highlight the same error but it does not breaks the code.
And in my machine it breaks the code and app doesn't start as it throws `Property 'getAuth' does not exist on type 'object'.  TS2339` as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just working, but not rightly implemented. This is a typescript issue that you can fix by defining types properly.

Following are the types you should have:

```
interface IAuth {
  userId: string;
  getAuth: boolean;
}

interface IAuthContext {
  auth: IAuth;
  setAuth: (state: IAuth) => void;
}
```

Here is the updated [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/auth-context-example-forked-f3f9k) which has the type issue fixed.